# Iterate through non-empty words from text files

Tags: python, io, iterator

> Given a file or directory, create an iterator that returns the non-empty words from the file or from all files *recursively* in the directory. Only process ".txt" files. Words are sequence of characters separated by whitespace.

```
class WordIterable:
    def __init__(self, path: str):
        root = Path(path)
        self._walker: Optional[Iterator[Path]] = None
        if root.is_dir():
            self._walker = root.rglob("*.txt")
        elif root.suffix == ".txt":
            self._walker = (p for p in [root])
        self._open_next_file()
        self._read_next_line()

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[str]:
        return self

    def __next__(self) -> str:
        next_word = self._next_word()
        if not next_word:
            self._read_next_line()
            next_word = self._next_word()
        if not next_word:
            self._close_file()
            self._open_next_file()
            self._read_next_line()
            next_word = self._next_word()
        return next_word if WordIterable._is_not_blank(next_word) else next(self)

    def _next_word(self) -> Optional[str]:
        return self._line.pop() if self._line else None

    def _read_next_line(self) -> None:
        self._line = self._fp.readline().split()[::-1]

    def _open_next_file(self) -> None:
        if self._walker:
            self._file: Path = next(self._walker, None)
            if self._file:
                self._fp = self._file.open(encoding="utf8")
                return
        raise StopIteration

    def _close_file(self) -> None:
        self._fp.close()

    @staticmethod
    def _is_not_blank(s: str) -> bool:
        return s and s != "\n"
```

This works but seems like a lot of code. Can we do better?

**Edit:**

> What is a "word" and a "non-empty word"?

Words are sequence of characters separated by whitespace.

> The question doesn't say to recursively processes a directory and it's sub-directories, but that's what the code appears to do.

It does now.

> The code only does ".txt" files.

Yes.

Comment: The question is vague and the code makes some assumptions that aren't in the question. For example, what is a "word" and a "non-empty word"? Just letters? What about numbers or punctuation? Also, the question doesn't say to recursively processes a directory and it's sub-directories, but that's what the code appears to do. Lastly, the question says to process all files in a directory, but the code only does ".txt" files.

Comment: @RootTwo This question was asked in an interview, and interview questions are sadly, but deliberately vague. I've added an edit for your follow up questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code seems overly complicated and complex for a relatively simple task.

```
from pathlib import Path

def words(file_or_path):
    path = Path(file_or_path)
    
    if path.is_dir():
        paths = path.rglob('*.txt')
    else:
        paths = (path, )
        
    for filepath in paths:
        yield from filepath.read_text().split()
```

The function can take a a directory name or a file name. For both cases, create an iterable, `paths`, of the files to be processed. This way, both cases can be handled by the same code.

For each filepath in `paths` use `Path.read_text()` to open the file, read it in, close the file, and return the text that was read. `str.split()` drops leading and trailing whitespace and then splits the string on whitespace. `yield from ...` yields each word in turn.

If you don't want to read an entire file in at once, replace the `yield from ...` with something like:

```
        with filepath.open() as f:
            for line in f:
                yield from line.split()
```

Comment: This is great, but I’d like to take it one step further by reading one word at a time instead of the whole line. However, I’m wondering if that can somehow backfire, since reading one character at a time until a white space is encountered isn’t exactly efficient. I wish there was a `readword` function.

Comment: The most commonly used python implementations will be based on C, its stdlib, and UNIX philosophy.
The IO there is build around lines and line-by-line processing. A `readword` function in python can be implemented very easily, but under the hood the implementation would read the line and discard everything except the word. You would not gain much

Comment: It would be totally possible, although definitely harder and less clean, to read the file in fixed-sized chunks instead of by line. And you would gain the ability to not crash if you come across a file with very long lines, e.g. a 32-gigabyte file without the `\n` character. Although I suppose such a file would likely [exceed `{LINE_MAX}`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html) (implementation-defined and only required to be >= 2048) and thus [wouldn't count as a "text file" according to the POSIX standard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446237)...

Comment: There's one issue with the `yield from` used here, it doesn't check for empty words, which is a requirement in the question. I changed it to `yield from filter(_is_not_blank, line.split())`.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, `.split()` should already filter out the blanks. Do you have an example input that causes it to return an empty word?

Comment: @RootTwo You're right, I tested with a file containing a line with `\n` only, a line with spaces and `\n`, and `split` handled those cases just fine.